# 7-zip not in Explorer++ context menu

Tags: windows, 7-zip

I use both 7-zip and Explorer++ quite a bit, but I can't seem to get Explorer++ to show the context menu items for 7-zip, like the Windows Explorer does?  Am I missing something?

In Windows Explorer if I right click a file, or a dir, or multiple files/dirs then I get a 7-zip menu, but never in Explorer++.

Comment: I can confirm that this issue persists for all context menu entries. For me the "Git Bash Here" context menu entry is missing. I am using Windows 11 and Explorer++ 1.4.0.2293 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, on two machines with this problem.

So what appears to fix it:  ensure that you are using 64-bit versions of both 7-zip and Explorer++, then all is well.